# Statistical testing in R: fisher test and logical variables as binary

Tags: r, data.table, logical-operators, statistical-test

I should choose and use right statistical testing between the variable “linolenic being greater than 0.33” and the variable “region being equal to Sardinia”. These are two binary variables, so I'm trying to use fisher.test, but how these could be changed into logical variables for table?

```
library(dslabs)
dt <- as.data.table(olive)
```

Comment: Note that Fisher's "exact" test is not very accurate: https://www.zotero.org/groups/2199991/feh/tags/fishers-exact-test/library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
table(dt[,.(Region = region == "Sardinia", Linolelic = linolenic > 0.33)])
#       Linolelic
#Region  FALSE TRUE
#  FALSE   220  254
#  TRUE     86   12
```

And then conveniently:

```
fisher.test(table(dt[,.(Region = region == "Sardinia", Linolelic = linolenic > 0.33)]))
#   Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data
#
#data:  table(dt[, .(Region = region == "Sardinia", Linolelic = linolenic > 0.33)])
#p-value = 4.58e-15
#alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
#95 percent confidence interval:
# 0.05870264 0.23036344
#sample estimates:
#odds ratio 
# 0.1212736
```